# Pattern in the differences between powers of 2 and 3

Tags: exponentiation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $n$ be some fixed, odd integer and $ q_k = 2^{\lceil \log_2(3^{k}n) \rceil} - 3^{k}n $ be the difference between $3^kn$ and the smallest power of two $\geq 3^kn$ .

Now the following two things seem to hold

**a)** $q_k \lt q_{k+1}$ implies $ q_{k+1}-3\cdot q_{k} = 2^{\lceil \log_2(3^{k}n) \rceil}$, or written out:
$$  (2^{\lceil \log_2(3^{k+1}n) \rceil} - 3^{k+1}n) - 3 \cdot (2^{\lceil \log_2(3^{k}n) \rceil} - 3^{k}n) = 2^{\lceil \log_2(3^{k}n) \rceil}  $$

**b)** $q_k \gt q_{k+1}$ implies $ q_{k+2} =  6q_{k} + q_{k+1} $, or written out:
$$ 2^{\lceil \log_2(3^{k+2}n) \rceil} - 3^{k+2}n = 6 \cdot (2^{\lceil \log_2(3^{k}n) \rceil} - 3^{k}n) + 2^{\lceil \log_2(3^{k+1}n) \rceil} - 3^{k+1}n$$

My questions are

- Is there any trivial explanation for that? I could imagine that both follow somehow from factoring but I cant quite wrap my head around it because of the $\lceil \dots \rceil$
- Is there anything we can say about $q_{k+2}$ when $q_k \lt q_{k+1}$?

Example for **a)**: Let $n = 17$, then $q_1= 13, q_2 = 103 $ and $ 103 - 3\cdot 13 = 2^{\lceil \log_2(3\cdot 13) \rceil}$

Example for **b)**: Let $n=15$, then $q_2=121, q_3=107, q_4=833 $ and $ 833 = 6 \cdot 121 - 107$

Comment: I didn't read/digest the whole question (yet), but $q_2 = 103 \rightarrow q_2 - 3\cdot 17 = 2^{\lceil \log_2(3\cdot 17) \rceil}$ doesn't look correct -- is there a typo.?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes was a typo, thanks

Comment: as $k$ is incremented, $\lceil\log_2(3^k n)\rceil$ is incremented by $1$ or $2$; if by $2$, then $q_{k+1}-3q_k=4\cdot2^{\lceil \log_2(3^{k}n) \rceil}-3^{k+1}n-3\cdot2^{\lceil \log_2(3^{k}n) \rceil}+3\times3^kn=2^{\lceil \log_2(3^{k}n) \rceil}$